# "I am to" vs "I have to"

Tags: word-choice, modality

I've seen a couple of sentences with "to be" + "infinitive with to" such as:

> You are to do that.

I know it has to do with a kind of obligation but I'm still wondering what is the difference between it and using "have to".
e.g:

> I am to tell you.

vs.

> I have to tell you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We were taught of these differences in modal verbs:

> **Must** {infinitive}

means an obligation due to higher order, like *duty* (of position or honour).

> **Should** {infinitive}

means that something is most prudent or sensible way of behaving.

> **Ought** to {infinitive}

means that was supposed to {infinitive} but didn't for some reason.

> **Have to** {infinitive}

means obligation due to (possibly adverse) circumstances.

> **Be to** {infinitive}

means obligation due to previous agreement or presumed way of behaving.

---

So, in your case,

> I **am to** tell you.

means that according to some agreement or protocol I have the obligation/task to inform you.

> I **have to** tell you.

means the circumstances force me to inform you (possibly against my wish, or I surrender to them).

Answer (score 0):

Obligation is usually expressed with "must+bare infinitive". As the modal verb must can only be used in present tense, for the other tenses a substitution ( have to do) is used. "I have to do it" is a shortening of "I have the obligation to do it".

"You are to come to the boss" is a shortening of "You are ordered to come to the boss". In some cases you can think of "obliged/demanded and similar forms" instead of "ordered".

Answer (score 0):

*I am to* is more formal than *I am supposed to*.  Both of these have a more neutral tone (i.e. less emotive) than *I have to*.